# ¿Como extraer datos saltados de un dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

necesito ayuda con este problema, espero me puedan ayudar, mi problema es que necesito extraer y ordenar los datos del siguiente dataframe:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

lo que necesito es extraer los datos en listas como mostré en la imagen según los colores:
en el siguiente orden 1.Amarillo, 2.Verde, 3.Rojo, 4.Azul oscuro, 5. naranja y así sucesivamente

comparto mi intento aunque resulto fallido y solo me lee las tres primeras listas

```
df = pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\Copicompu\Desktop\Libro3.xlsx', header = 0)
df1=pd.DataFrame(df)
data_1 =(df1.iloc[::3]) 

lista = [] 
for i in range(len(data_1)):
    lista.append(list(data_1.iloc[:,i]))
```

respuesta:

```
[[5.5, 5, 4, 23.6, 0][1.2, 0, 2.4, 20.2, 0][0, 0, 0.3, 7.6, 0][0, 0, 0, 18.2, 6.8][0, 18, 10.2, 17.2, 2.6][0, 0, 3.1, 2.6, 3.2][2.5, 51.8, 3.2, 16.4, 9.3][12.3, 0, 0, 0, 12][52, 0, 4, 44.4, 50.7]
```

¡¡Ayuda Porfavor¡¡

Comment: Hola Gustavo, puedes poner como debería ser el output? y si puedes el input en código(como diccionario) para poder probarlo tu código en un Notebooks?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Voy a comenzar por crear un dataframe de ejemplo sobre el que operar, para no tener que copiar a mano los números del tuyo. Este tiene también tres columnas, pero he puesto los números consecutivos en cada columna para que sea más fácil después ver el patrón.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"P01": range(0, 15), "P02":range(15, 30), "P03": range(30,45)})
```

El dataframe que resulta es el siguiente:

```html
    P01  P02  P03
0     0   15   30
1     1   16   31
2     2   17   32
3     3   18   33
4     4   19   34
5     5   20   35
6     6   21   36
7     7   22   37
8     8   23   38
9     9   24   39
10   10   25   40
11   11   26   41
12   12   27   42
13   13   28   43
14   14   29   44
```

Entiendo que se trata de seleccionar según el siguiente patrón:

- Primero las filas múltiplo de 3 en la columna P01, luego en la P02, luego en la P03
- Después las filas 1, 4, 7... en esas columnas
- Finalmente las filas 2, 5, 8.... en esas columnas

Necesitas por tanto varios bucles anidados, uno para ir variando el "offset" (la fila por la que hay que comenzar, es decir, la 0, la 1 o la 2), otro para variar la columna seleccionada y finalmente otro para variar el índice de modo que comience en el offset correspondiente y avance de 3 en 3 por esa columna.

Los valores que vayas encontrando de esta forma no tengo claro qué quieres hacer con ellos. Voy a meterlos todos en una sola lista plana, y ya lo adaptas tú a tu necesidad, o preguntas en un comentario:

```
r = []
for offset in range(0,3):
  for column in range(0,3):
    for item in range(offset, len(df), 3):
      r.append(df.iloc[item, column])
```

El resultado en `r` es (editado para legibilidad):

```
[
 0, 3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18, 21, 24, 27, 30, 33, 36, 39, 42, 
 1, 4, 7, 10, 13, 16, 19, 22, 25, 28, 31, 34, 37, 40, 43, 
 2, 5, 8, 11, 14, 17, 20, 23, 26, 29, 32, 35, 38, 41, 44
]
```

### Ampliación

Puedes evitarte el bucle interno si usas el slice apropiado en un `.iloc`:

```
r = []
for offset in range(0,3):
  for column in range(0,3):
    r.extend(df.iloc[offset::3, column].tolist())
```

Esto produciría el mismo resultado que el código antes visto (o sea, una lista plana).

Y si cambias el `r.extend()` por `r.append()` puedes obtener una lista anidada, que no sé si es lo que buscas, como esta:

```
[
 [0, 3, 6, 9, 12], [15, 18, 21, 24, 27], [30, 33, 36, 39, 42],
 [1, 4, 7, 10, 13], [16, 19, 22, 25, 28], [31, 34, 37, 40, 43],
 [2, 5, 8, 11, 14], [17, 20, 23, 26, 29], [32, 35, 38, 41, 44]
]
```

Comment: muchas gracias por tu ayuda es justo lo que estaba buscando para poder continuar con mi programa, me has ayudado demasiado

Comment: Hola tengo una duda si en un caso existieran mas que tres columnas como podria organizar los datos

Answer (score 1):

Me resulta más fácil obtener el resultado que creo que buscas si pienso en tu dataframe como en una lista de listas.

De esa forma podrías concatenar esas listas y luego agruparlas siguiendo los saltos que quieres, que en tu caso son 9

```
# convertimos el dataframe a una lista plana
valores = [_ for sub in df.values.tolist() for _ in sub]

grupos = 9 # este es el número de grupos que quieres

# ahora seleccionamos de la lista los elementos según el salto que quieres
out = [valores[x::grupos] for x in range(0, grupos)]
```

La salida sería algo así:

```
[[5.5, 5.0, 4.0, 23.6, 0.0], [1.2, 0.0, 2.4, 20.2, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.3, 7.6, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 18.2, 6.8], [0.0, 18.0, 10.2, 17.2, 2.6], [0.0, 0.0, 3.1, 2.6, 3.2], [2.5, 51.8, 3.2, 16.4, 9.3], [12.3, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 12.0], [52.0, 0.0, 4.0, 44.4, 50.7]]
```